# Are there a faster developing alternative than backbone js? / Backbone alternative

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have been developing backbone applications for 2 months and I must say that this framework is awesome. Nevertheless when I compare the development velocity of backbone js against Rails/Ruby web app, I feel that javascript with backbone take too much time to being developed. Do you know if exist a backbone alternative that works like rails works? I mean I am looking for a javascript framework that works like rails for ruby (commands to generate controllers, model, view, etc).

Thanks for all.

Comment: Maybe http://www.meteor.com

Comment: https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/grunt-bbb, backbone boiler plate is a framework for create backbone projects.  It comes with all sorts of commands to generate boilerplate and to build projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a broad question, but yes, there are **tons** of JS frameworks. [Ember](http://emberjs.com/) seems to be the new hottness (Yehuda Katz is on the core team, so you will find some rails inspired love there). It's structured (unlike a lot of the freewheeling JS frameworks), and gaining a lot of momentum these days.

As far as I know, ember does not include a CLI/Utility for generating views in the way that you want. There is a third-party plugin [Ember Tools](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-tools) that may be similar to what you want.

To see a list of other frameworks, and some great examples, check  out [to do MVC](http://todomvc.com/)

Comment: Yes I know it is a broad question (I tried to make it the smallest as I can). Does ember has this command behavior in order to generate controller/views/models??

Comment: Updated answer with link to Ember Tools; that should give you something similar to the rails commands you want.

Comment: Thank you guys, the admins closed this question as not constructive. At least for me was really constructive, I learned the existence of new tools for js.